# Django -Nested forloops django to create a table from csv

Tags: python, django, django-templates

i imported a csv and i want to create a table from that. The csv is parsed and update_or_create function help to actualice the database.
the quantities of csv's columns is variable also the rows. Then, (i think) i am forced to do two classic forloops for parse it. The problem is that not working or i am doing something wrong.

the first forloops reads the headers and the second go inside each object. 
but i don´t know how to call the attribute of each object

```
<table >
{% for h in archivo.fieldnames %} // headers are "isbn" and "stock"
       {% for x in objeto_nuevo %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{h}}</td> //render "isbn", ok.
            <td>{{{{x}}.{{h}}}}</td> // i want object1.isbn but dont render.
         </tr>
          {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
</table>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: can you also provide the csv layout and your model definition?

Comment: bit of a guess, but `<td>{{x.h}}</td>` may be what you are after; hard to tell without more info.

Answer (score 0):

More information about variable in template [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#variables)

```
<table >
{% for h in archivo.fieldnames %} // headers are "isbn" and "stock"
       {% for x in objeto_nuevo %}
       <tr>
           <td>{{ h }}</td>
           <td>{{ x.h }}</td> <!-- Show h attribute of object x -->
       </tr>
       {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show me what {{ x }} and {{ x.h }} display ?
h is only header? right? So header in table should be in <th>, not a <tr>.